# How to add multiple instances under an elb

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add 4 ec2 instances under my elb using the **count** function. However, when i execute the template i am getting below error:

**Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_elb" "web":
  19:   instances = ["${aws_instance.web.*.id}"]
Inappropriate value for attribute "instances": element 0: string required.**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.aws_region}"
}

resource "aws_elb" "web" {
  name = "terraform-example-elb"

  # The same availability zone as our instances
  availability_zones = ["${aws_instance.web.*.availability_zone}"]

  listener {
    instance_port     = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port           = 80
    lb_protocol       = "http"
  }

  # The instances are registered automatically
  instances = ["${aws_instance.web.*.id}"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  instance_type = "m1.small"
  ami           = "${lookup(var.aws_amis, var.aws_region)}"

  # This will create 4 instances
  count = 4
}
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `availability_zones` and `instances` arguments expects a list, but the returned data using the splat operator also returns a list. Looks like you're passing in a list of lists using the square brackets which is why it's failing.

For example using v0.12 notation:

```
availability_zones = aws_instance.web[*].availability_zone
```

Using v0.11 notation:

```
availability_zones = aws_instance.web.*.availability_zone
```

Couple of notes:

- The ELB won't "work" because its failing health checks until the instances start broadcasting on 80
- `m1.small` is an older generation

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with user11391264 that your ELB won't work because it's missing health checks....Please add the code below to your script.

```
health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 5
    timeout             = 5
    target              = "${var.elb_healthcheck_target}"
    interval            = 30
}
cross_zone_load_balancing   = true
connection_draining         = true
connection_draining_timeout = 400

variable "elb_healthcheck_target" {
  default = "HTTP:80/"
}
```